# Android: I can't pass a date to my string ID

Tags: java, android, date, time, tostring

The App is supposed to have two Buttons and a TextView, one for date and another for time. Clicking the date button will give you the current date in the TextView and same for the time button. The updateTime class is where I'm having my issue. I've tried different ways of passing that date to an ID.

Here's my source code and notes:

```
package com.CS211D.DateAndTime;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.DateFormat;
/*
 * This is the activity for my Android App that gives you the date and time when you click on a button. I'm having trouble trying to figure out the date syntax 
 */
//*******************TimeAndDateActivity*******************
public class TimeAndDateActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    Button btn;
    DateFormat fmtDateTime = DateFormat.getDateAndTimeInstance(); //other utils I've tried
    Calendar mycal = Calendar.getInstance();                      //with no avail
    @Override
    //*******************onCreate*******************
    public void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
        super.onCreate(b);
        btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.time);   //Time Button
        btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.day);    //Date Button

    }
        //*******************onClick*******************
        public void onClick(View v) //Called when one of the buttons above is clicked is clicked
        {
             updateTime();
        }
            //*******************updateTime*******************
            private void updateTime()
            {
                t = getTime()
                btn.setText(getDate().toString(R.id.time));//Most of the methods I try eclipse says 
                                                           //the method is either undefined or incompatible
                                                           //with the object
            }


}
```

Comment: Whats this...getDate().toString(R.id.time)???...Whats your intention here?? and you are using the same reference "btn" for both the buttons..

Comment: Seriously you need to learn how to code in java first. That code is a complete and utter mess.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code -

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
String date = String.valueOf(day) + "-" + String.valueOf(month) + "-" +String.valueOf(year);
btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.day); 
btn.setText(date);
```

Try out this code.

Comment: I'm trying to get the current date, not set one

Comment: I think that is almost what he is looking for except, from reading (and it wasn't easy) I think he has two buttons that he wants to update the single textview. e.g click one button and the textview shows the current date click another button and the textview shows the current time.

Answer (score 0):

Create two different button objects and different onclick listener for each button.

```
Button butdate = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.day);
Button buttime = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.time);
butdate.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View v )
        {
            //code to set date in textview
        }
    });


buttime.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View v )
        {
            //code to set time in textview
        }
    });
```